# Where are the hex files compiled by Arduino?

Tags: arduino

Where does the Arduino IDE save the binaries on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In the Arduino software: go to *File* -> *Preferences* and then select *Show verbose output during* -> *compilation*.

[image]

Finally, when you are compiling, the program will show you lots of data. At the last lines, you will find the path<sup>1</sup> to the `.hex` file.

---

<sup>1</sup>Every time the path changes!

Comment: It's true the that path changes every time. If you want to locate the files without having to read though the output, see my answer for 2 tools you can use to script whatever work you need to do with the files.

Answer (score 37):

Arduino 1.6.5 has a new command: Under the `Sketch` menu, select `Export compiled Binary`, then `Show Sketch Folder`. There it is.

Answer (score 7):

Arduino IDE uses the [mktemp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp) command to create the temp directory on Mac and Linux. However, on Mac the default $TMPDIR env var is not /tmp/ as it is on Linux. On Mac it's under /var/folders and it is randomly generated on boot. That complicates things a little, but here are tricks you can add to your toolkit (as aliases, functions, shell scripts, etc.) to help you find what you need.

### To find the hex files

```
find $TMPDIR -name \*.hex -exec ls -lrt {} \; #<-- you need that backslash before and space after the semicolon
```

### To find build directories

```
ls -ldrt $TMPDIR/build*
```

---

**NOTE:** The `ls` flags of `r` and `t` cause the listing to be "reverse" sorted by "time" respectively. This means that the newest will be on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

What UDalillu said. The trick also works on Windows. On XP it ended up in C:\Documents and Settings\Your_User_Name\Local Settings\Temp\buildxxxxx\ (the xxx number changes for each build, pick the most recent).

Answer (score 0):

The arduino web page http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess 
described

> During a "Verify" the .hex file is written to /tmp (on Mac and Linux) or \Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Temp (on Windows)

I am using fedora19 64bit, and when i check my /tmp the build directory created is
/tmp/build8102....tmp/

Comment: The page you reference is simply wrong. While both of the *nix versions of Arduino IDE use the mktemp command to create the temp directory, on Mac the default $TMPDIR env var is not /tmp/ it's under /var/folders and it is randomly generated on boot. So on a Mac, do `ls -ldrt $TMPDIR/build*`

Comment: Windows path is wrong. I posted the right one, for XP at least.

Answer (score -1):

I made a simple tutorial [here](http://onlinehandsontraining.com/generating-hex-file-arduino-sketch/) with images

Answer (score -2):

It is very beautifully explained in the following blog 
[Where to find Arduino Hex files or Output Binaries](https://www.kanda.com/blog/microcontrollers/avr-microcontrollers/find-arduino-hex-files-output-binaries/)
I hope this helps :)

Comment: That's windows, the OP specifically requests mac

Comment: Cool @taxilian I was just trying to help and moreover, I think that was a good article on a similar topic and would help someone visiting the question by it's header "Where are the hex files compiled by Arduino?"