# How to measure the amount of memory or RAM consumed by a code on Arduino Mega or Due

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

Can anybody tell me how to measure the consumed RAM for a particular code running on Arduino Mega or Due.

Answer (score 3):

There is two kinds of numbers to this question:
*Global static usage* and *current run time*.

The static estimated usage can be determined by adding the following line to (if it does not already exist)

.\arduino-1.5.5\hardware\arduino\avr\boards.txt

```
uno.upload.maximum_ram_size=2048
```

This then allows the compiler to output the additional 2nd line in the following example in the IDE's result window

```
Binary sketch size: 25,880 bytes (of a 32,256 byte maximum)
Estimated used SRAM memory: 990 bytes (of a 2048 byte maximum)
```

To see the amount of memory used at any given point. Including memory space currently in use, that exists while only in functions and members. This includes the HEAP and such. I use the following [MemoryFree library](https://github.com/mpflaga/Arduino-MemoryFree) at specific points in the code to reveal the high-water. The readme explains how to save unnecessarily/unintentionally used RAM by prints.

---

Note: That while the original Arduino IDE 1.0.5's boards.txt files does contain these ram_sizes, it does not actually use display usage. Where the original Arduino IDE 1.5.5 does, along with Arduino ERW 1.0.5 does (an non-supported fork).

Comment: uno.upload.maximum_ram_size=2048 - Will this work for arduino mega 2560 and arduino due as well? I am using arduino ide 1.5.2. Will it work there?

Comment: For mega2560.upload.maximum_ram_size=8192   Not sure but would expect it to work for Due... 98304

Comment: I suddenly ponder that maximum_ram_size in the boards.txt, may only be a feature of "Arduino ERW"s IDE. and not in the stock IDE's.

Comment: Will this work in any version of the IDE ? I am using version 1.5.2

Comment: Will this work in any version of the IDE ? I used 1.0.5 and edited the boards.txt file with the line mega2560.upload.maximum_ram_size=8192. But nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

In my Arduino IDE 2.1.0

I edit the file: `/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/boards.txt`
but the second line don't appear

After read:
[check-ram-memory-usage-arduino-optimization](https://oscarliang.com/check-ram-memory-usage-arduino-optimization)

[measuring-free-memory](https://learn.adafruit.com/memories-of-an-arduino/measuring-free-memory)

I tried:
[Show vervose output during compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607834/where-are-the-hex-files-compiled-by-arduino)
and use `avr-size /tmp/build4042914391435450796.tmp/XXXXXXX.cpp.elf`

then i get my memory used

Best Regards!

Answer (score -1):

```
int freeRam () {
  extern int __heap_start, *__brkval; 
  int v; 
  int fr = (int) &v - (__brkval == 0 ? (int) &__heap_start : (int) __brkval); 
  Serial.print("Free ram: ");
  Serial.println(fr);

}
```

Comment: On my Due this reports a negative number.