# Is it possible to send binary data directly to Arduino?

Tags: binary, arduino

Hello I have been using Arduino's for a really long time and I have made a mini computer that uses an Atmega328p and a nokia 5110 screen. I wrote a load of Arduino code to make a basic operating system. I'm 99.9% sure that when you compile and send the code to the Arduino it is converted to binary, stored as binary and run as binary. I was wondering if it's possible to skip the 'write code in Arduino process' and just write a ton of binary and send that to the chip. I'm sure that is difficult and hard but I jut want to know if it is possible. Please let me know if it is possible to send binary directly to the Atmega328p.

Comment: Why you named the question with "microchip"?

Comment: it is possible to write hex file to arduino with a programmer. But really i dont know how to receive hex from Arduino IDE. Only thing i know is that visual micro ide [pro mode] supports writing without compiling if were no changes in code.

Comment: Yes, how do I write hex file to arduino

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Arduino IDE compiles your Arduino code into a binary (or hex) file that it uses to program the chip. You can find the hex file that the Arduino IDE created [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11654333).

If you already have a hex file, you can program your Arduino directly without the IDE using a tool such as [AVRdude](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-trinket/programming-with-avrdude).

While it's technically possible to write Arduino firmware in binary, this would be extraordinarily tedious. If you want to write your code in something lower level than the Arduino language, you could use C/C++ or assembly. Some discussion on the [Arduino forums](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=37130.0).

Comment: so lets say I wanted to tell the Arduino to turn pin 13 on. How would I write that in hex and send it to the arduino

Comment: also is it possible to send it over ISP?

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.avr-tutorials.com/digital/digital-input-output-assembly-programming-atmel-8-bits-avr-microcontrollers) for an intro to digital IO in AVR assembly.

Comment: ...and yes AVRdude supports programming over ISP.